# enableAngularMotor in ammo js doesn't seem to function when changing object from BoxBufferGeometry to BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, game-physics, ammo.js

I'm creating a pinball game using three.js and ammo.js and am having issues rotating the flippers using enableAngularMotor when using bufferGeometry cloned from a loaded GLTF file, when the same code using a BoxBufferGeometry works ok.

The original test build I had a threejs BoxBufferGeometry block wired up to the hinge, and got that working. I have shifted the code to the loaded callback on the gltf loader in three.js and the geometry from the new nicer model clones ok, and can be read, but the same hinge wiring code doesn't seem to rotate the flipper.

````
                    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
                    let mass = ms;
                    loader.load(whichFile,function ( gltf ) {
                        gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
                        gltf.scene; // THREE.Scene
                        gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
                        gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
                        gltf.asset; // Object
                        gltf.scene.scale.set(Size[0],Size[1],Size[2]);
                        gltf.scene.position.set(Pos[0],Pos[1],Pos[2]);
                        gltf.asset.castShadow = true;
                        gltf.asset.receiveShadow = true;

                        gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
                            if (child.isMesh) {
                                child.castShadow = true;
                                child.receiveShadow = true;
                                let geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( child.geometry );
                                let qCircX = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, child.material);
                                //scene.add(qCircX);
                                qCircX.scale.set(Size[0],Size[1],Size[2]);
                                qCircX.position.set(Pos[0],Pos[1],Pos[2]);
                                geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                                geometry.mergeVertices();
                                geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                                child.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );
                                let qCirc = new THREE.Mesh(child.geometry, child.material);
                                qCirc.scale.set(Size[0],Size[1],Size[2]);
                                qCirc.position.set(Pos[0],Pos[1],Pos[2]);
                                qCirc.castShadow = true;
                                qCirc.receiveShadow = true;
                                scene.add(qCirc);

                                let transform = new Ammo.btTransform();
                                transform.setIdentity();
                                transform.setOrigin( new Ammo.btVector3( Pos[0],Pos[1],Pos[2] ) );
                                let motionState = new Ammo.btDefaultMotionState( transform );
                                let vertices, face, triangles = [];

                                vertices = geometry.vertices;

                                vertices = generateVertexMesh(geometry, vertices, triangles);

                                let i, triangle, triangle_mesh = new Ammo.btTriangleMesh;
                                let _vec3_1 = new Ammo.btVector3(0,0,0);
                                let _vec3_2 = new Ammo.btVector3(0,0,0);
                                let _vec3_3 = new Ammo.btVector3(0,0,0);
                                for ( i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ) {
                                    triangle = triangles[i];
                                    _vec3_1.setX(triangle[0].x);
                                    _vec3_1.setY(triangle[0].y);
                                    _vec3_1.setZ(triangle[0].z);
                                    _vec3_2.setX(triangle[1].x);
                                    _vec3_2.setY(triangle[1].y);
                                    _vec3_2.setZ(triangle[1].z);
                                    _vec3_3.setX(triangle[2].x);
                                    _vec3_3.setY(triangle[2].y);
                                    _vec3_3.setZ(triangle[2].z);
                                    triangle_mesh.addTriangle(
                                        _vec3_1,
                                        _vec3_2,
                                        _vec3_3,
                                        true
                                    );
                                }
                                let colSurround = new Ammo.btBvhTriangleMeshShape( triangle_mesh, true, true );
                                let localInertia = new Ammo.btVector3( 0, 0, 0 );
                                colSurround.calculateLocalInertia( mass, localInertia );
                                let rbInfo = new Ammo.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo( mass, motionState, colSurround, localInertia );
                                let body = new Ammo.btRigidBody( rbInfo );
                                body.setRestitution(rest);
                                qCirc.userData.physicsBody = body;

                                qCirc.name = objName;

                                collidableMeshList.push(qCirc);

                                if(addToScoreColliders){
                                    scoreList.push(objName);
                                }

                                //console.log(ballArray);
                                if ( mass > 0 ) {
                                    rigidBodies.push( qCirc );
                                    //console.log(rigidBodies);
                                    body.setActivationState( 4 );
                                }
                                physicsWorld.addRigidBody( body );


                                if(objName == "flipperL"){
                                    let pos = {x:-16,y:0,z:27}, posBumper = {x:0,y:0,z:0}, scaleHinge = {x:1,y:1,z:1}, scaleBumper = {x:1,y:1,z:1}, quat = {x:0,y:0,z:0,w:1}, quatBumper = {x:0,y:0,z:0,w:1}, mass = 0, massBumper = 9;

                                    // create the hinge and bumper objects
                                    leftHinge = createPhysicsGeometry(0xff0000,pos,scaleHinge,quat,mass,"leftHinge",0,[0,0], true);

                                    // Hinge constraint to move the bumper
                                    let pivotA = new Ammo.btVector3( 0, 0.5, 0 ),pivotB = new Ammo.btVector3( -1.5, -3, 0 ),axis = new Ammo.btVector3( 0, 1, 0 );

                                    leftHingeConstraint = new Ammo.btHingeConstraint( leftHinge.userData.physicsBody, qCirc.userData.physicsBody, pivotA, pivotB, axis, axis, true );
                                    leftHingeConstraint.setLimit(0, Math.PI/2 * 0.5, 0.9, 0.3, 1);
                                    physicsWorld.addConstraint( leftHingeConstraint, true );
                                    leftHingeActive = true;
                                    bumperGeoms[0] = qCirc;
                                }

                                if(objName == "flipperR"){
                                    let pos = {x:16,y:0,z:27}, posBumper = {x:0,y:0,z:0}, scaleHinge = {x:1,y:1,z:1}, scaleBumper = {x:1,y:1,z:1}, quat = {x:0, y:0, z:0, w: 1},quatBumper = {x:0,y:0,z:0,w:1}, mass = 0, massBumper = 9;

                                    // create the hinge and bumper objects
                                    rightHinge = createPhysicsGeometry(0xff0000,pos,scaleHinge,quat,mass,"rightHinge",0,[0,0], true);

                                    // Hinge constraint to move the bumper
                                    let pivotA = new Ammo.btVector3( 0, 0.5, 0 ),pivotB = new Ammo.btVector3( 1.5, -3, 0 ),axis = new Ammo.btVector3( 0, 1, 0 );

                                    //console.log(bumperArray);

                                    rightHingeConstraint = new Ammo.btHingeConstraint( rightHinge.userData.physicsBody, qCirc.userData.physicsBody, pivotA, pivotB, axis, axis, true );
                                    rightHingeConstraint.setLimit(-Math.PI/2 * 0.5, 0, 0.9, 0.3, 1);
                                    physicsWorld.addConstraint( rightHingeConstraint, true );
                                    rightHingeActive = true;
                                    bumperGeoms[1] = qCirc;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    // called while loading is progressing
                    function ( xhr ) {
                        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
                    },
                    // called when loading has errors
                    function ( error ) {
                        console.log( 'An error happened : ' + error );
                    });
                }```

When an area of the screen is pressed, the angular motor is enabled with a multiplier to turn the flipper, whereas now the flipper doesn't rotate. I don't get any errors logging to the console, and logging geometry to check it's loaded ok is fine.
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I took an alternate approach and make the gltf scene a child of the existing simple cuboid flipper.